# how to install pyqt5 in debian strect

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, debian, pyqt5

How can I install pyqt5 for python3.5 in debian stretch?

I am getting the following error

```
user@host:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package python3-pyqt5
user@host:~$

user@host:~$ python3
Python 3.5.3rc1 (default, Jan  3 2017, 04:40:57) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20161229] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there were some network issue  which once resolved , resolved this issue too

Answer (score 2):

`python3-pyqt5` is a valid package for apt get

you need to update your package repo

try `dpkg -l python3-pyqt5` to see if your computer can find the package at all

Comment: Thanks for your help, there were some network issue in my case.

Comment: no problem, if your issue is resolved, please mark the answer